# jQuery CrystalsCollector Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a Crystal Collector game where you have to click a crystal and get to a random number based on each crystal having a hidden value.  In my click functions I can have 4 different click functions for each crystal but would like to consolidate 4 actions into one function.  Here are the two snippets of code for the HTML and javascript pages we need to complete this:

HTML......

```
<div class="buttons">       
    <img class="image" id="image1" src="assets/images/crystal1.png">
    <img class="image" id="image2" src="assets/images/crystal2.png">
    <img class="image" id="image3" src="assets/images/crystal3.png">
    <img class="image" id="image4" src="assets/images/crystal4.png">
</div>
```

javaScript.....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*102+19);

$("#numberToGet").text(random);

var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
var num3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
var num4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);

var userTotal= 0;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;

$("#numberWins").text(wins);
$("#numberLosses").text(losses);

function reset() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*102+19);
    console.log(random);
    $("#numberToGet").text(random);
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
    var num3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
    var num4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
    userTotal = 0;
    $("#score").text(userTotal);
}

function winner() {
    alert("You Won!!");
    wins++;
    $("#numberWins").text(wins);
    reset();
}

function loser() {
    alert("You Lose!!");
    losses++;
    $("#numberLosses").text(losses);
    reset();
}

$("#image1").on("click", function() {
    userTotal = userTotal + num1;
    console.log("New userTotal " + userTotal);
    $("#score").text(userTotal);

    if (userTotal === random) {
        winner()
    }

    else if (userTotal > random) {
        loser()
    } 
})
```

});

For the bottom "image1" click function, I want to apply this to all 4 crystals each still having a different hidden value.  I included a class "image" for each picture and thought if I called the click function for the class "image" and then somehow created a value attribute for the random number each crystal is worth in there somewhere that this would achieve what I want.  Any advice to push me in the right direction would help greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are going for but if you are creating the crystals in html then go ahead and assign them all a class. So that way they are all apart of class="crystals". Next you want to give them an onclick handler. So to catch you up it should look like this.

```
<img class="crystals" onclick="popCrystal(event, 'image1')" id="image1" src="assets/images/crystal1.png">
<img class="crystals" onclick="popCrystal(event, 'image2')" id="image2" src="assets/images/crystal1.png">
<img class="crystals" onclick="popCrystal(event, 'image3')" id="image3" src="assets/images/crystal1.png">
<img class="crystals" onclick="popCrystal(event, 'image4')" id="image4" src="assets/images/crystal1.png">
```

and then we will make a function called popCrystal to be called when someone clicks a crystal.

```
function popCrystal(evt, getCrystal) {
document.getElementById(getCrystal).style.float = "right";
}
```

If you have any questions just tag me in the post.

edit: I just realized this is hard to read... Im sorry about that. I am at work so I am not going to rewrite it but I will explain a little bit.

This is how onclick works:

onclick is an event listener that gets triggered with the DOM element is clicked. It calls a function which we called "popCrystal". popCrystal has to arguments which are event, and the id of the current div. So you see how we go from image1 to image4 along side the respective id's?  That's so we can call the specific element later on.

finally we get to the javascript. This is where we actually make the "popCrystal" function. We will populate it with the same to arguments as the one in the div elements. Inside the function is where you will put your code telling it what to do. I simply used float right to show you how it selects the individual elements.

Hope that helps even though my explanation is quite sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but you could do something like...

```
//....

var crystalValues = {};
crystalValues[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
crystalValues[2] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
crystalValues[3] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);
crystalValues[4] = Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);

//.... more code here


function getCrystalHandler(crystalKey) {
   return function() {
    userTotal = userTotal + crystalValues[crystalKey];
    console.log("New userTotal " + userTotal);
    $("#score").text(userTotal);

    if (userTotal === random) {
        winner()
    }

    else if (userTotal > random) {
        loser()
    } 
}
}

$("#image1").on("click", getCrystalHandler(1));
$("#image2").on("click", getCrystalHandler(2));
$("#image3").on("click", getCrystalHandler(3));
$("#image4").on("click", getCrystalHandler(4));
```